# Get a list of checked checkboxes in a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I want to get a list of names of checkboxes that are selected in a div with certain id. How would I do that using jQuery?

E.g., for this div I want to get array ["c_n_0"; "c_n_3"] or a string "c_n_0;c_n_3"

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="c_n_0" checked="checked" />Option 1
    <input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="c_n_1" />Option 2
    <input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="c_n_2" />Option 3
    <input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="c_n_3" checked="checked" />Option 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Combination of two previous answers:

```
var selected = [];
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: and another combo: var selected = $('#checkboxes input:checked').map(function(i,el){return el.name;}).get();  // add .join(';') to get a combined string

Comment: @Alex LE. How Do i get only the count of the selected checkboxes? I just need to check if any of the checkboxes inside the div is checked or not.

Comment: @Ashish. Just write: var count = $('#checkboxes input:checked').length;

Comment: Unnecessary call of constructor `var selected = new Array();`. Better (cheaper) with `var selected = [];`

Comment: How do I get it on `change` function?

Comment: To complement this answer, you can also use [attributeStartsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector) to do something more fancy like `$('[id^="chkbx"]:checked')` to select all selected ones based on their IDs.

Comment: My comment might sound silly but I spent hours figuring out the hard way that `$('[checked]')` is not the same as `$(':checked')`; the former only gives you those elements, whose HTML has been written as `checked`, even though now they are unchecked! at the moment you look whereas the latter gives you all elements that are actually checked at the moment you look. (my setup = FF 79.0 64bit)

Answer (score 74):

Would this do?

```
var selected = [];
$('div#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
   }
});
```

Comment: $(this).checked does not work.  Use if ($(this).attr('checked')) or if ($(this).is(':checked'))

Comment: if `.attr('checked')` or `.prop('checked')` or `.is(':checked')` does not work, try `.get(0).checked`

Answer (score 42):

```
$("#checkboxes").children("input:checked")
```

will give you an array of the elements themselves. If you just specifically need the names:

```
$("#checkboxes").children("input:checked").map(function() {
    return this.name;
});
```

Comment: I think that should be return this.name or return $(this).attr('name');

Comment: `$("#checkboxes :checked").map(...)` would be more concise. As Jansen points out, it should be `$(this).attr("name")`; but I would consider a simple `this.name` which should be just as compatible.

Comment: This was great for the simple map. I changed `children` to `find` to look deeper, and needed jquery attributes so used `$(this)`  (and wrote this comment for when I come looking again...)

Comment: Hey, I came looking again, and found it! (I know, not a very useful comment, but I couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 32):

I needed the count of all checkboxes which are checked. Instead of writing a loop i did this

```
$(".myCheckBoxClass:checked").length;
```

Compare it with the total number of checkboxes to see if they are equal. Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 16):

This works for me.

```
var selecteditems = [];

$("#Div").find("input:checked").each(function (i, ob) { 
    selecteditems.push($(ob).val());
});
```

Comment: It's really nice that you're not using `this` in the `each` function.

Answer (score 7):

You could also give them all the same name [so they are an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627813/how-to-get-an-array-with-jquery-multiple-input-with-the-same-name), but give them different ***values***:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="c_n[]" value="c_n_0" checked="checked" />Option 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="c_n[]" value="c_n_1" />Option 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="c_n[]" value="c_n_2" />Option 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="c_n[]" value="c_n_3" checked="checked" />Option 4
</div>
```

You can then get only the value of only the ticked ones [using map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627813/how-to-get-an-array-with-jquery-multiple-input-with-the-same-name#2627834):

```
$('#checkboxes input:checked[name="c_n[]"]')
            .map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to get quantity of selected checkboxes:

```
var selected = []; // initialize array
    $('div#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           selected.push($(this));
       }
    });
var selectedQuantity = selected.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var agencias = [];
 $('#Div input:checked').each(function(index, item){
 agencias.push(item.nextElementSibling.attributes.for.nodeValue);
 });
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
function listselect() {
                var selected = [];
                $('.SelectPhone').prop('checked', function () {

                    selected.push($(this).val());
                });

                alert(selected.length);
```

```html
     <input type="checkbox" name="SelectPhone" class="SelectPhone"  value="1" />
         <input type="checkbox" name="SelectPhone" class="SelectPhone"  value="2" />
         <input type="checkbox" name="SelectPhone" class="SelectPhone"  value="3" />
        <button onclick="listselect()">show count</button>
```