# How to get an Array with jQuery, multiple <input> with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form where users can add input fields with jQuery.

```
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[]" />
```

After submitting the form I get an array in PHP.

I want to handle this with the `$.ajax()` but I have no idea how to turn my `<input>`s to an array in jQuery.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Using [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var values = $("input[id='task']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

If you change or remove the id (which should be unique), you may also use the selector `$("input[name='task\\[\\]']")`

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ixeze3

Comment: this is working good with the 1,2,3 so i'll use this with the explode function of php to get it sorted

thanks @all for helping

Comment: @x4tje - no problem. You don't have to use explode - note that `values` is an array, not a string. It depends on how you do your AJAX call, or course.

Comment: why do we need `.get()` for?

Comment: The .get() flattens the array of values into a string.  If you did want the actual Javascript array of values, you should remove the ".get()".

Comment: @orrd - `$(...)` returns an array-like jQuery wrapper. [`$(...).get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a real array of real DOM nodes, not a string.

Comment: how can I do if I want to add for each element of the array, each index [n], another value? Example:

    <input type="text" class="name" />
    <input type="text" class="surname" />

Comment: @Gabz - I'd target their container, something like `$('.row').map(function(){var row = $(this); return {name: row.find('.name').val(), surname: row.find('.surname').val()};}).get();`, which results in an array of objects, not just values. Feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your code if you need additional help. Thanks!

Comment: I can't make it work :( thanks anyway, I'll post a new question

Comment: it works thanks! I forgot to change the function to alert the content of the array on the screen and it was blocking all the code when submitting!

Comment: Be careful with .map(), in some browsers it returns an array but in others it returns an object `m.fn.init[]` (Chrome). This latter one cannot be stringified by JSON.stringify(). Specifically, the following two are NOT equivalent: `var arr=$('input[name="foo"]').map(function(){return this.value}).get()` with `var arr=[]; $('input[name="foo"]').each(function(){arr.push(this.value)})`. In the first case `arr` is not an Array whereas in the latter case it is. `JSON.stringify(arr)` fails for the former, but works for the latter.

Comment: you are genius .. I have do this for select box.

Answer (score 35):

For multiple elements, you should give it a class rather than id eg:

```
<input type="text" class="task" name="task[]" />
```

Now you can get those using jquery something like this:

```
$('.task').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @Sarfraz please check it http://codepen.io/sidaurukfreddy/pen/XNroJW
how can i prevent if kode barang has same value ? thanks

Answer (score 17):

Firstly, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID on a page - ID should be unique.

You could just remove the id attribute and and replace it with:

```
<input type='text' name='task'>
```

and to get an array of the values of task do

```
var taskArray = new Array();
$("input[name=task]").each(function() {
   taskArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 10):

To catch the names array, i use that:

```
$("input[name*='task']")
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer here.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use same id for multiple elements in a document. Keep the ids different and name same for the elements.

```
<input type="text" id="task1" name="task" />
<input type="text" id="task2" name="task" />
<input type="text" id="task3" name="task" />
<input type="text" id="task4" name="task" />
<input type="text" id="task5" name="task" />

var newArray = new Array();

$("input:text[name=task]").each(function(){
    newArray.push($(this));
});
```

Comment: @rahul: that won't do because he is dealing with multiple text boxes not one. If you know PHP, notice the name of the text box `task[]` which means there are supposed to be more than one text boxes.

Comment: @rahul: your update won't help still in terms of making php array which can be done if the `[]` is suffixed with the name of the field.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="task[]" class="form-control" id="task">
```

JS:

```
var tasks= new Array();
$('input[name^="task"]').each(function() 
{
tasks.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want selector get the same id, use：

```
$("[id=task]:eq(0)").val();
$("[id=task]:eq(1)").val();
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Q:How to access name array text field

```
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[]" />
```

Answer - Using Input name array :

```
$('input[name="task\\[\\]"]').eq(0).val()
$('input[name="task\\[\\]"]').eq(index).val()
```