# Send list/array as parameter with jQuery getJson

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, parameter-passing, getjson, url-parameters

I have the following where I'm trying to send list/array to MVC controller method:

```
var id = [];
var inStock = [];

$table.find('tbody>tr').each(function() {
    id.push($(this).find('.id').text());
    inStock.push($(this).find('.stocked').attr('checked'));
});

var params = {};
params.ids = id;
params.stocked = inStock; 

$.getJSON('MyApp/UpdateStockList', params, function() {
    alert('finished');
});
```

in my contoller:

```
public JsonResult UpdateStockList(int[] ids, bool[] stocked) { }
```

both paramaters are null.

Note that if I change the params to single items

```
params.ids = 1;
params.stocked = true; 

public JsonResult UpdateStockList(int ids, bool stocked) { }
```

then it works ok, so I don't think it's a routing issue.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try setting the `traditional` flag:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/UpdateStockList',
    data: { ids: [1, 2, 3], stocked: [true, false] },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.status);
    }
});
```

works fine with:

```
public ActionResult UpdateStockList(int[] ids, bool[] stocked)
{
    return Json(new { status = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: genius, thank you! It seems there is a bug in getJson with 1.4.2, see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getjson-breaks-with-1-4-2-when-parameter-argument-is-an-array

Comment: This is not a bug. It is a breaking change from previous the version. That's why they introduced the `traditional` parameter.

Answer (score 24):

Besides calling `.ajax()` instead of `.getJSON()` as Darin suggests or setting the global `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional` to `true` as jrduncans suggests, you can also pass the result of calling [the jQuery `.param()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) on your `params` object:

```
var id = [];
var inStock = [];

$table.find('tbody>tr').each(function() {
    id.push($(this).find('.id').text());
    inStock.push($(this).find('.stocked').attr('checked'));
});

var params = {};
params.ids = id;
params.stocked = inStock; 

$.getJSON('MyApp/UpdateStockList', $.param(params, true), function() {
    alert('finished');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree. While Darin pointed out the traditional flag (you're awesome don't get me wrong), this answer let's you use getJson, which is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, while it seems that jquery provides a "traditional" flag to toggle this behavior on jQuery.ajax, it does not on jQuery.getJSON.  One way to get around this would to be set the flag globally:

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

See the documentation for jQuery.param: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/
Also see the release notes for this change: http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14 (search for 'traditional')

Answer (score 0):

In the view, generate [multiple named fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529443/jquery-get-input-array-field#19529465) (not `id`, as `id` should be unique per field), noting the use of [`Name` not `name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057865/asp-net-mvc-3-override-name-attribute-with-textboxfor#17638187):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SomeDictionary)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Value.SomeString, new { Name = "someString[]" })
}
```

Then retrieve the input field values using jQuery, [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627813/how-to-get-an-array-with-jquery-multiple-input-with-the-same-name#2627834):

```
var myArrayValues = $('input[name="someString[]"]').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

You can use this directly in jQuery / AJAX as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/MyAction",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        someStrings: $('input[name="someString[]"]').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get(),
        someDates: $('input[name="someDate[]"]').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get(),
```

Then in the controller action in MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(string[] someStrings, DateTime[] someDates...
```