# ASP.NET MVC 3: Override "name" attribute with TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

Is it possible when using `Html.TextBoxFor` to override the name attribute?

I have tried with no success. I need to use TextBoxFor to get client side validation to work, however for reasons I won't go into I need the name of the textbox to be different from the generated one.

I have tried the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Data, new { name = Model.Key + "_Data", id = Model.Key + "_Data" })
```

Which works for ID but not name. Is this possible?

**Update**: Looking into the code for TextBoxFor. It doesn't look like there is an easy way. Hopefully someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: What is the data type of 'Data'

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920935/control-name-in-textboxfor-in-mvc3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064363/mvc2-impossible-to-change-the-name-with-textboxfor

Comment: Those questions are asking something slightly different. Also - this is the older of the three, so I think you mean duplicated by.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765499/946773

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Rob, actually there is a much simpler way. Instead of **name**, use ***Name***:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Data, new { Name = Model.Key + "_Data", id = Model.Key + "_Data" })
```

Comment: Case-sensitive it is @highwingers, this tiny detail has the potential to save hours.

Comment: Overkill.. Name but id X_X

Comment: @Vladimirs, sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Weird, "id" is not case-sensitive (works fine with Id and id) but "name" isn't.

Comment: With ASP.NET 4, providing `Name` results in two attributes, `Name` and `name`, and the model binder uses the `name`.

Comment: But handling two different properties whose names differ only by case is a recipe for a maintenance nightmare.....

Comment: +1 bc this worked. still looking for a way to tell Chrome to put last name in a field instead of email.

Comment: @Brad, can you describe the problem you are facing? Maybe create a new question here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Anar, building a register form, put in the `name` attributes, but Chrome is still putting email in the `email` AND `lname` fields. I might get around to it, but right now, I'm just working on the stuff that's quick to fix or flat out broken. Deadlines and all :-\

Comment: @Brad, maybe Chrome is overwriting the last name field by using the autofill feature of the browser. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Works, but isn't documented, so it's liable to change... I'm afraid to use this "feature" unless someone has an official reference?

Comment: Really old, may help someone, to make the validation to work @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Data, string.Empty, new { data_valmsg_for = Model.Key + "_Data" }).

Comment: Anyone know why this would not work in asp.net core mvc 7?

Answer (score 44):

Are you asking this because you want to apply a prefix to the name? If so, you can do this by setting `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` in your Controller.

I learnt a lot about this stuff from [Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

Comment: This looks like the winner! Beautiful.

Comment: Yeah they hid that one nicely didn't they :)

Comment: This just saved me some headache and code duplication.

Answer (score 14):

EditorFor has an overload where you can supply the `name` attribute as a parameter:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(expression, null, name)
```

Comment: Would have saved me hours if I found this hours ago, haha

Comment: Interesting, but there is no overload for the name attribute for similar helpers like DropDownListFor, you have to specify it in the html attributes parameter (with a capital N in Name).

Answer (score 10):

It is called Microsoft **GOTCHA**...

Use the name in caps, like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reply.Answer, new { Name = "Whatyouwant" })
```

Comment: It really makes the difference, if you use @name, it will not get overridden. Very hard to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292027.aspx). you can pass string as template name if you want to make sure textbox is rendered even if property type is not string. If property is string already, it does not need `templatename` explicitly to render textbox, so you can pass `null`. Note that it does not require id parameter explicitly, it will infer it from element name. And all the validation things are still active with EditorFor

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Data, "string", Model.Key + "_Data")
```

Answer (score 7):

ben's answer got me what I was looking for except you need to wrap in in Html.Raw

```
@Html.Raw(Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Data).ToString().Replace("Data", "NewData"))
```

Answer (score 4):

a little bit "unpretty"=), try:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Data).ToString().Replace("Data", "NewData")
```

Comment: Seems like a nice easy way to do it. If a little hacky :-)

Comment: umm, this way, wouldnt you rather just take normal Html.TexBox.. since any static typing is gone anyway after the replace

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works! I hope that help!

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "80", @id = "NomeFilter", @Name = "NomeFilter" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Something, "name", "name", new {@class = "form-control" })
```

Not sure which of those two string parameters in the middle do the work, but it worked only when I typed both of them.

Comment: It's Id and Name. this worked for me. I went through all above answers and non of them worked, but this 1. Thanks.

Comment: `public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string templateName, string htmlFieldName, object additionalViewData);`. No idea what `templateName` is supposed to be, so I used `null`. For `htmlFieldName` I used the name of the parameter (in my case "ipmi" instead of "IPMI"). That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

For this example, I was disabling form fields based on permissions, but still showing them. I had a hidden field to send the value to the controller, but wanted a different field name in the EditorFor.
First param after model value represents the "name" property, second is the new name.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, "name", "UserNameDisabled", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled"} });
```

Results in:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" disabled="disabled" id="UserNameDisabled" name="UserNameDisabled" type="text" value="someEnteredValue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, your already providing the ID you should simply be able to use the method "TextBox" instead of "TextBoxFor" and it will work fine client side and server side. In addition, although the accepted answer will work but will produce duplicate Name attributes on your tag if you inspect it using a browser. The below solution does not have that problem.

MvcHtmlString Html.TextBox(string name, string value, object htmlAttributes)

```
@Html.TextBox(Model.Key + "_Data", Model.Key, new { id = Model.Key + "_Data" }
```