# MVC2: Impossible to change the name with TextBoxFor?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html.textboxfor

I want to manually define id and name for textbox like that:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @id = "txt1", @name = "txt1" })%>
```

But only the id is changed, not the name attribute, why?

```
<input id="txt1" name="Name" type="text" value="">
```

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920935/control-name-in-textboxfor-in-mvc3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057865/asp-net-mvc-3-override-name-attribute-with-textboxfor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the strongly typed lambda version for this, you'd need to use the older version

```
Html.TextBox("txt1",new {@id = "txt1"})
```

Comment: This is a solution, yet it is not "THE" solution.
For instance, TextBoxFor() includes unobtrusive validation attributes depending on the attributes that decorate a given property and that are IClientValidatable. TextBox() doesn't.

Comment: @IsaacLlopis: check my answer and be surprised... :) what a capital letter can do!

Answer (score 17):

This is ok:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { Name = "txt1" })%>
```

Do you write "**Name**" instead of "name"?

Output:

```
<input  name="txt1" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Using ASP.NET MVC 3, '@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { Name = "user_name" })' produces '<input Name="user_name" id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />' (both Name and name attributes).

Comment: It works in MVC4 as well, rendering
`<input name="txt1" id="txt1" readonly="True" type="text" value="">`

Comment: Confirmed in MVC2 as well.

Answer (score 10):

Actually you can... just use `Name` with first letter capitalized instead of `name`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { Name = "myName" })
```

Comment: Wow I've had this problem for ages, `name` wouldn't work but `Name` did! It even works for `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to use `TextBoxFor()`, you can change the name of the property on your model, which should be easy if you're using dedicated ViewModels as is recommended. However I admit it's a recommendation I don't always follow myself.