# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HttpRequest'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, httprequest

I am trying to get a value from a textbox of my View.

This is my View:

```
    @model MyDataIndexViewModel

@{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <h1>Meine Daten</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    var item = Model.User;
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 myDataTitle">Email</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBox("txtEmail", "", new { placeholder = item.Email})
            </div>
        </div>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="/ChangeMyData/Save">Speichern</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        var email = Request["txtEmail"].ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

I get the error just as it says in the Title. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**VIEW:**

```
@model MyDataIndexViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "CONTROLLER_NAME"))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <h1>Meine Daten</h1>
    </div>
</div>
var item = Model.User;
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 myDataTitle">Email</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            @Html.TextBox("txtEmail", "", new { placeholder = item.Email, id="txtEmail"})
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <a class="submit btn btn-default pull-right">Speichern</a>
</div>
</div>
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Save()
{
    var email = Request.Form["txtEmail"].ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use strongly-typed viewmodel binding:

**View**

```
@model MyDataIndexViewModel

@* other stuff *@

@Html.TextBox("txtEmail", Model.Email)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyDataIndexViewModel model)
{
    var email = model.Email;
    return View();
}
```

Or use a `TextBoxFor` directly for model binding:

```
@model MyDataIndexViewModel

@* other stuff *@

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
```

Or if you still want to use `HttpRequest` members, [`Request.Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) collection (a `NameValueCollection`) is available to retrieve text from `txtEmail` input:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{
    var email = Request.Form["txtEmail"].ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Note that `Request["txtEmail"]` is discouraged due to no compile time safety applied for it, because the key value may retrieved from `Request.QueryString`, `Request.Form` or other `HttpRequestBase` members.

Similar issue:

[MVC TextBox with name specified not binding model on post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359355/mvc-textbox-with-name-specified-not-binding-model-on-post)

[Access form data into controller using Request in ASP.NET MVC](http://techfunda.com/howto/215/access-form-data-into-controller-using-request)

Comment: You can use indexing - and if you test OP's code you will see that `var email = Request["txtEmail"].ToString();` works just fine

Comment: Well, as Darin pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088450/how-to-retrieve-form-values-from-httppost-dictionary-or) I surprised it is possible to use `Request["Key"]` but not recommended due to possibility to fail in runtime.

Comment: `Controller.Request` is `HttpRequestBase` and has a default [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.item(v=vs.110).aspx) property (but of course binding to a model is far better). OP has not shown us the code throwing the error (and their view does not even have a form or submit button, just a link which will never go to the `[HttpPost]` method)