# set "id" and "name" for @HtmlEditorFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to set `id` and `name` for `@Html.EditorFor`, but this isn't working:

```cs
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.value, new { @id = "testid1", @name="testname1"})
```

How do I set `id` and `name`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`EditorFor` does not allow for adding htmlAttributes. For the specific types of editors you'll have to use `TextBoxFor` (or whatever type you're using).

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.value, new { id = "testid1", name="Testname1" })
```

You can also create a [custom editor template](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/) for the particular type you're creating an editor for.

Answer (score 15):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Beds[i].BedName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Name = "BedName" + Model.Beds[i].bedId, @id = "BedName" + Model.Beds[i].bedId } })
```

Use **Name** insted of @name and add htmlAttributes in your code its working for me

Answer (score 7):

EditorFor allows to set name and id property (tested with .Net 4.6.1) `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.value, null, "Testname1")`
will generate `<input class="text-box single-line" id="Testname1" name="Testname1" type="text" >`