# Passing values from the view to the controller in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass these textbox values to the controller:

```
@model DTOs.QuestionDTO

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddQuestion";
}

<h2>AddQuestion</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddQuestionDB", "Exam"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Question</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionDes)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionDes , new { @id="question" , @name="question"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionDes)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer1 , new { @id="a1" , @name="a1"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer2 , new { @id="a2" , @name="a2"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer3 , new { @id="a3" , @name="a3"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer3)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer4)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer4 , new { @id="a4" , @name="a4"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer4)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Correct)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Correct , new { @id="correct" , @name="correct"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Correct)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Login", "Login")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

this is how my controller method looks like:

```
public ActionResult AddQuestionDB(string question, string a1, string a2, string a3, string a4, string correct)
        {
            ViewBag.a1 = a1;
            ViewBag.a2 = a2;
            ViewBag.a3 = a3;
            ViewBag.a4 = a4;
            ViewBag.correct = correct;
            return View();
        }
```

And i have created a View to display this Viewbag variables... but these variables wont come up.
it seem to be that these variables are null..

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddQuestionDB";
}

<h2>AddQuestionDB</h2>

<p>@Session["q"]</p>
<p>@ViewBag.question</p>
<p>@ViewBag.a1</p>
<p>@ViewBag.a2</p>
<p>@ViewBag.a3</p>
<p>@ViewBag.a4</p>
<p>@ViewBag.correct</p>
```

this is how my DTO looks like:

```
namespace DTOs
{
    public class QuestionDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionDes { get; set; }
        public string Answer1 { get; set; }
        public string Answer2 { get; set; }
        public string Answer3 { get; set; }
        public string Answer4 { get; set; }
        public int Correct { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Can you please explain, how i should do this??
thank you!!!

Comment: Can't tell, but don't see a form. Need a form and if you're using default routing, SomeController with [HttpPost] method SomeMethod would route as /Some/SomeMethod. The parameter would most likely be DTOs.QuestionDTO objectNameGoesHere as it looks like you're using html helpers so you should have proper binding.

Comment: ok thanks i'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of -

```
public ActionResult AddQuestionDB(string question, string a1, string a2, string a3, string a4, string correct)
{
    // Your custom code
     return View();
}
```

have this code -

```
 public ActionResult AddQuestionDB(QuestionDTO question)
 {
      // Use 'question' object here to get posted values.
      return View();
 }
```

I replicated your scenario in a small sample project on my local, here is the outcome when I debugged the code with breakpoint -

[image]

Comment: This is how it should be done, though you should also pass the `question` model back to the view to display its values (unlike with ViewBag): `return View(question);`

Answer (score 1):

[`Html.EditorFor` does not support setting attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868747/set-id-and-name-for-htmleditorfor), which is why your original code wasn't working. The `name` attribute didn't match the parameter names in your controller action, so they were assigned `null`.

You can either use [@ramiramilu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27668838/497356), or you could use `TextBoxFor` instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Correct , new { id="correct" , Name="correct"})
```

(Note that `Name` must be capitalized in order for this to work).

**Example**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZfzCaZ