# razor´s problem: generating an attribute "name" for an input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with Razor that when I invoke the helper @EditorFor (), the result in the HTML generates an  with the name and id attribute with different values each.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, "Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10"> 

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onBlur = "completarCodigo()", @value = "@ViewBag.cliente" } })               
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#OCRDSAPF2_CardName").autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '@Url.Action("getClientes", "Cotizacions")',
                                    data: { term: $("#OCRDSAPF2_CardName").val() },
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        response(result);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                    <strong>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, "", new { @class = "bg-danger" })
                    </strong>
                </div>
        </div>
```

the output html:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="ERROR:El campo Cliente no puede estar vacio." id="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" name="OCRDSAPF2.CardName" onblur="completarCodigo()" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

I want:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="ERROR:El campo Cliente no puede estar vacio." id="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" name="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" onblur="completarCodigo()" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

sorry my English

Comment: No es una pregunta valido por lengua C.

Comment: For better or worse, SO requires English in questions and answers.  Please either translate to English or ask on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not written in English as required on the the main SO site.

Comment: See:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868747/set-id-and-name-for-htmleditorfor)