# adding css and id selector to input box (razor helper)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside razor view I have textbox rendered by razor helper

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Caption, 
       new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I want to add css id class together with this form-control class so I tried

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Caption, 
        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id="myId" } })
```

but this doesnt work.

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Caption, 
        new { @class = "form-control", @id="myId" } )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By **default** you have an `id`, is **`Caption`**.

If you want to change it, acccording to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16847237/3790486) you have to change from `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor`. To do this, we need to remove `new { htmlAttributes` because [`TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703535(v=vs.118).aspx) expects to get `htmlAttributes` and [`EditorFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462(v=vs.118).aspx) expects to get `additionViewData`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Caption, new { @class = "form-control", @id="myId" } )
```

I want to mention that your code, as it is, changed the `id` when i tested.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Caption, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id="myId" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`TextBoxFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) if you want to specify htmlAttributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Caption, 
    new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Have a look at [this SO post(Dimitro's Answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc)