# Pass multiple array as parameters to Home Controller using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I have to make a json call to home controller where I need to pass multiple arrays.

```js
 var assetids = new Array(N);
 var faultTimes = new Array(N);
 var messages = new Array(N);
 var curtailments = new Array(N);

 //populate above arrays with values then make a JSON call

$.getJSON('Home/AcknowledgeMany', {
                        assetid: assetids,
                        loggedBy: $("#UserName").text(),
                        faultTime: faultTimes,
                        message: messages,
                        curtailment: curtailments
                    }, function (result) {
                          alert(result); 
                       }
```

The homecontroller has following action result

```java
public string AcknowledgeMany(int[] assetId, string loggedBy, string[] faultTime, string[] message, string[] curtailment)
 {

 return("Acknowledged");
}
```

I receive null values for all the arrays when I make this call. Can someone help me passing arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `traditional` flag

For detail help see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676883/send-list-array-as-parameter-with-jquery-getjson) question

Comment: This works great. Thanks. I wonder if I could achieve the same without using $.ajax. Does $.getJSON provide an option of traditional:true ?

Comment: I don't think so, As jquery site doesn't have it in its description http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: If your problem is solved you can acknowledge by accepting that answer, So your question also helps other solving there problem :)