# Jquery get input array field

Tags: jquery

I've found similar questions here but nothing works for me.

have inputs like:

```
<input type="text" value="2" name="pages_title[1]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="pages_title[2]">
```

trying to get these fields like:

```
$('input[name="pages_title[]"]')
```

but have empty results :(

how to get all fields?
I can only get it like `$('input[name="pages_title[1]"]')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)

Comment: Ah, misread question. Close vote is wrong...need to use starts with selector.

Comment: @epascarello - how would begin with help to get all of them?

Comment: I made a simple plugin that will recursively generate a JSON object representation of these "multidimensional input fields": http://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/MyWZdN

Answer (score 117):

Use the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('input[name^="pages_title"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TsqNF/1/)

**Note:** In agreement with @epascarello that the better solution is to add a class to the elements and reference that class.

Comment: This solution has a caveat, if any other input starts with a similar name, it would also be included.
e.g "pages_title_secondary"

Answer (score 37):

```js
const textValues = $.map($('input[type=text][name="pages_title[]"]'), function(el) { return el.value; });
   console.log(textValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello" name="pages_title[]">
<input type="text" value="World" name="pages_title[]">
```

Comment: To iterate over each one, use `$('input[name="pages_title[]"]').each(function() { var aValue = $(this).val(); });`

Comment: sorry but this will not work, as I described in my question. It will work only if i have fields names like pages_title[] but not pages_title[1] pages_title[2] pages_title[3]

Comment: @Dementic but that is fully legal to have that. You could have more dimensions name="page_tile[1][name]" and name="page_title[2][name]" so you need to support [1] etc

Comment: @Dss - it is legal, but the naming comes to represent an array,
`[1]` would represent a different array then `[2]`

Comment: -1 It's not only legal, but it's an absolute must when I have a variable number of fields associated to the field-array, and no guarantee either of the order or inclusion of each one.  I *have* to be able to supply unique ID's that I can count on once submitted.

Answer (score 26):

use map method we can get input values that stored in array.

```
var values = $("input[name='pages_title[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
var elems = $( "[name^='pages_title']" );
```

But a better solution is to add a class to the elements and reference the class. The reason it is a faster look up.

Comment: and then what happens in the case of `name="pages_titles"` ? also, why use a class, when its clear the `name` should be the same? extra markup for fun?

Comment: No it is not fun... because the `^=` is a lot slower than a class selector. It has to parse strings and check for a match. And I have no idea what you mean with the `name="pages_titles"`

Comment: as per your answer, starts with, will also catch `pages_titles` (instead of `pages_title`). i agree that he should narrow down he's selector to something like `#divId[name='pages_title']` but why adding a class? the difference would be so little, it wont be noticed.

Comment: one more thing (sorry for picking..) since ajax was not mentioned, this form might be submitted regularly, and as for your `add class` solution, he will get no results at the server side.

Comment: This answer is interesting and even with deeper thoughts about regex parse consuming, for plug-in, for example, it would be better choice to go with classes - much faster, agree with epascarello.

Answer (score 13):

Put the input name between **single quotes** so that the brackets `[]` are treated as a string

```
var multi_members="";
$("input[name='bayi[]']:checked:enabled").each(function() {
    multi_members=$(this).val()+","+multi_members;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can give your input textboxes class names, like so:

```
<input type="text" value="2" name="pages_title[1]" class="pages_title">
<input type="text" value="1" name="pages_title[2]" class="pages_title">
```

and iterate like so:

```
$('input.pages_title').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: That's great answer. It help a lot of me.

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way, is to use a Propper Form and to use [jQuery.serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

```
<!-- a form with any type of input -->
<form class="a-form">
    <select name="field[something]">...</select>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field[somethingelse]" ... />
    <input type="radio" name="field[somethingelse2]" ... />
    <input type="text" name="field[somethingelse3]" ... />
</form>

<!-- sample ajax call -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form.a-form').serializeArray(),
        success: function(response){
            ...
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The Values will be available in PHP as `$_POST['field'][INDEX]`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the contain selector:

> [[name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/): selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

```
$( document ).on( "keyup", "input[name*='pages_title']", function() {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Most used is this:

```
$("input[name='varname[]']").map( function(key){
    console.log(key+':'+$(this).val());
})
```

Whit that you get the key of the array possition and the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the square brackets with double backslashes like this:

`$('input[name="pages_title\\[\\]"]')`

Answer (score 1):

In order to select an element by attribute having a specific characteristic you may create a new selector like in the following snippet using a regex pattern. The usage of regex is intended  to make flexible the new selector as much as possible:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    nameMatch: function (ele, idx, selector) {
        var rpStr = (selector[3] || '').replace(/^\/(.*)\/$/, '$1');
        return (new RegExp(rpStr)).test(ele.name);
    }
});


//
// use of selector
//
$('input:nameMatch(/^pages_title\\[\\d\\]$/)').each(function(idx, ele) {
  console.log(ele.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="2" name="pages_title[1]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="pages_title[2]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="pages_title[]">
```

Another solution can be based on:

> - [[name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/): selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.
> - [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/): reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

- a regex pattern

```js
var selectedEle = $(':input[name^="pages_title"]').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    //
    // test if the name attribute matches the pattern.....
    //
    return  /^pages_title\[\d\]$/.test(ele.name);
});
selectedEle.each(function(idx, ele) {
    console.log(ele.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="2" name="pages_title[1]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="pages_title[2]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="pages_title[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = $("input[name='page_title[]']")
  .map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  })
  .get();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].