# Getting value of text field with array type name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input text field like below

```
<input type="checkbox" value="9961103777" name="mobile[]">
```

I just want to get the value using jquery. I tried this but not working:

```
jQuery('input[name=mobile[]]');
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) as well as wrapping the name of your input inside double quotes `" "`:

```
jQuery('input[name="mobile[]"]').val()
```

Comment: You need to wrap the name in `" "`

Answer (score 1):

Put attribute value in quotes. To fetch its value use `.val()`

```
jQuery('input[name="mobile[]"]')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgNyS/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("input[name='mobile[]']").val();
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for, worked great!

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

Refer this post [Jquery get input array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529443/jquery-get-input-array-field)

```
$('input[name^="mobile"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TsqNF/1/)