# Javascript does not recognize HTML arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to pass this kind of HTML input to JavaScript so that it recognizes these array values?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="collection[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" id="collection[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="collection[]" value="2">]
```

The only idea I have (never played with js this way, tbh) is to reach it through:

```
$("#collection").val();
```

But I got **undefined** error. I have no other idea how to make javascript recognize that variable **collection** is an array and has to passed as such.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? Decide which checkboxes are checked?

Comment: Sorry, didn't change name to id. Doesn't work either.

@taylorcressy: I'm trying to pass values of selected checkboxes to json and then, through jQuery, to a php file so that only selected checkboxes are processed. But I need javascript to recognize which checkboxes to pass...

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs, change it to name

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529443/jquery-get-input-array-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, IDs need to be unique within your document. So set by 'name' not by id.

You can use

```
$('#someid').is(":checked");
```

for individually checking each checkbox, or loop through them with a jQuery selector

To loop through them set

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="2">
```

Then with jQuery,

```
$('input[name=checkboxes]:checked').each(function(i, e) {
        e.val();   //The value of the checkbox that is selected
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have Duplicate Ids. Though duplicate IDs will give you desired output in this case, it is invalid to use them for multiple elements.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="collection[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="collection[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="collection[]" value="2">
```

There are many ways you can access array based elements.

jQuery **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)**: Alternative is **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3y8v/)

```
$("[name='collection[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()
```

---

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3y8v/1/) for checking checked inputs.
To get the checked checkbox,

```
$('input').change(function () {
    console.log($("[name='collection[]']:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#collection")
```

It mean's ,"Find me an element which id's equal collection on page" , of course it can't find anything. You can use .each function and you can use checkboxes attributes. For example ;

```
var myCheckBoxArray = []

$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i,elm){
    myCheckBoxArray.push(elm);
});
```

Comment: He only wants the checkboxes that are checked