# Calculate multiple rows of jquery dynamic form

Tags: jquery

I have tried to find out the summation of  multiple rows of jquery forms. But could not.

**Input :**

```
<input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" " />
```

**Jquery**

```
$('input').keyup(function()
{ 
   var num  = Number($('#item_quantity').val());  
   var sum = 0;
   for(i=0; i<num.size(); i++)
   {
       sum += num;
       document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
   }
});
```

**Output :**

```
Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting by id: `$('#item_quantity')`, whilst using the `name` attribute.
Instead you should use the `$('[name=item_quantity[]]')` selector.

Something like this should work:

```
$('input').keyup(function()
{ 
   const $elements = $('[name=item_quantity[]]');
   let sum = 0;
   for (let i=0; i<$elements.size(); i++)
   {
       sum += Number($elements[i].val());
   }
   $('#total').html(sum);
});
```

You can checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529465/1493235) for more information about this selector.

Comment: Note that the `$('input')` selector is **very** general, be careful with this, because it might trigger unnecessary recalculations, when other, non-total related fields are changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keyup(function()
{ 
   var names=document.getElementsByName('item_quantity[]');
   var sum =0;
   for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)  
   {
      sum += Number(names[key].value);
      document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
   }
});
```