# make array from the input values with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have html form with names like `...name="bulk[]"...`. Is there way to get all values of `bulk` in array with jquery? Ex

```
$('[name*="bulk"]').val().join('|');// this is incorrect just to show how I need that
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an Array with jQuery, multiple <input> with the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627813/how-to-get-an-array-with-jquery-multiple-input-with-the-same-name)

Comment: yes seems like duplicate :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is made for this purpose

```
var myarray = $('[name^="bulk"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Comment: it says join is not a function

Comment: I think what you want is to use join on a native js array, see my answer - you just need the additional call to 'get'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `get` to turn it to a true array!

```
$('[name*="bulk"]').map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var obj = [];
$('[name^="bulk"]').each(function(){
    obj.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to add the names

```
var myarray = $('[name^="bulk"]').map(function(){
return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$elements = $(selector).map(function() { return $(this).val() });
var element_array = $.makeArray($elements);
```

This will make valid array from jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var arr = [];
$("[name*="bulk"] :input").each(function(){
   var input = $(this);
   arr.push(input.val())
});
```

It will get only `input` type fields