# Select multiple var in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, loops

I want to send multiple attributes of HTML element generated by php while loop by Ajax call.

For example:

```
<div id="chart" >
    $i=1;
    while($i<10){
       <input type="text" calss="item" id="$i" >   
       $i++;
    }
 </div>
```

Above code represent the part of the information which I want to send through ajax code as below. 
The input ids differ from pages representing different item. My question is how to select those ids to get val() inside input & declare them as variables at the same time so that i can pass these values through AJAX call.
    `

```
var main = function() {

$('.btn').click(function(){
var item1=$('#1').val();
var item2=$('#2').val();
var item3=$('#3').val();
var item4=$('#4').val();
var item5=$('#5').val();
var item6=$('#6').val();
var item7=$('#7').val();
var item8=$('#8').val();
var item9=$('#9').val();

 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "something.php",
    cache:0,
    data:({
     "item1":item1,
     "item2":item2,
    "item3":item3,
   "item4":item4,
    "item5":item5,
    "item6":item6,
    "item7":item7,
    "item8":item8,
    "item9":item9,
    }),
    success:function(result){
    $('#chart').html(result);
    },
    complete:function(){
        alert('good!!');
    }   
     });
 });

 }
   $(document).ready(main);`
```

Comment: Firstly you need to set your `calss` into `class`

Comment: As your question is lil bit confusing but what you want is the value of your text box, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: quiz have lack of information, need more clear description..

Comment: I modified my question  and sorry for that ambiguous information

Comment: Its seems you don't have values within your input, so how could you get values by `$('#1').val();`

Comment: well I wanna make people type in that input  so I can get the information with val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

select with jquery by ID

```
var myInputObject = $("#1");
alert(myInputObject.val());
```

`$("#1")` returns your  field with the id `1`

or select by class

```
var myInputObjects = $(".item");
```

`$(".item")` returns all  field's with the attribute `class=item`

[jQuery selectors API-Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

CREATE:

```
<div id="chart" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){
        $('<input/>', {
           id: i,
           class: "item",
           type: "text"
        }).appendTo('#myFields');
    {
</script>
```

--> Creates 10 `input` elements and append it to `<div id="chart" />`

Create a post request:

```
var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "something.php",
    cache:0,
    data : postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data: return data from server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fails     
    }
});
```

-> sends your form as a `POST` request to `something.php`... there you can get your values by `$_POST["1"]`

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression. What I really trying to say is that I use a loop to generate each id and dont know how to declare them one by one in an single AJAX call

Comment: thx for replying so fast!!.  I just modified my original question which is a little bit different but I still appreciate your answer

Comment: ahh.. :) now i know what do you want to do :) ->updatet

Comment: so what's within $_POST  will be a serialize array, then how do I classify them after ajax. Can I get the  text of id =1 of an input by $_POST['1']??

Answer (score 0):

I used a method here [How to get an Array with jQuery, multiple <input> with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627813/how-to-get-an-array-with-jquery-multiple-input-with-the-same-name) to solve my problem in the end

```
       var main=function(){
      $('.btn').click(function(){
       var items-name = $('input[class="item"]').map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
            }).get();
       var items-id=$('input[class="item"]').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "something.php",
        cache:0,
        data:({
         "name":items-name,
         "id":items-id                  
        }),
         success:function(){
        alert('done');
        }
       });
        });
         }
        $(document).ready(main);
```