# How to get an array of all checkboxes passed to the next page via _POST using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post, checkbox

How to get an array of all checkboxes selected on the page, and then passing it to the next page (in this case php, so it can be picked up by php _POST function). I have come up with this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selected = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
       selected.push($(this).val());
  });
$('#od').submit(function() {
  alert(this.selected); // *See note below
  $.post('receiver.php', {'registration': selected});
  return false;
});

});

</script>
```

But is does not seem to work :( It returns null, as if no checkboxes would have been added to the array, or maybe the post function is wrong. Can you point me in the right direction here?

Comment: It should be `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`

Comment: See this [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: Nitpicking: it's spelt `$_POST` and it isn't a function, it's a variable. Particularly, it's a superglobal array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the following of issues:

1. You read the checked items on page load, thus ignoring all changes made by the user. Move that code to the `submit()` handler.
2. Your debugging code (`alert(this.selected)`) tries to display the value of the `selected` property for the form node. It isn't a reference to your JavaScript global variable `selected`. I suggest you use a proper debugging tool such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com); alerts are highly unsuitable.
3. You sucessfully send the *values* of checked items. You just ignore the field *name* and rename everything to `registration`. That looks intended, otherwise report back:

   ```
   {'registration': selected}
   ```

I suppose you can make jQuery serialize the values for you but fixing these little details in your code should do the trick anyway.

Comment: How can I serialize the result, before it is posted to the next page?

Comment: I figured out that serialization does not work on this example as expected, so I needed to use .serializeArray(); instead

Answer (score 0):

I think `$("input:checkbox:checked")` should be `$("input[type="checkbox"]:checked")

Answer (score 0):

Or simply: $('input:checked', '#form-container');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#od').submit(function() {
  var selected = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').toArray();
  $.post('receiver.php', {'registration': selected});
  return false;
});
```

The Data being posted might need to be split up.....

Comment: This example is very close, because the form actually submits, and it seems to pass the variables to the correct page, nevertheless there is "" in the database cell, where the info should end up, so I reckon it passes "null" as an empty array. Could it be a problem with checkboxes themselfes?

Comment: I meant one field of the row.