# Check status of all checkboxes in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several check box in a form I just wanna way to check whether they are checked or not .

if checked i need to store their id in the database(that i can do it ) . But my question is how to determine whether are checked or not instead of checking for each check box on at a time .

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Role Id<input type="text" name="roll_id"/><br>
Role Name<input type="text" name="roll_name"/><br>
Role Description<textarea name="roll_desc"></textarea><br>
<br>
<br>

Screen1<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tab1<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_view" value="s1_t1_view" >view<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_add" value="s1_t1_add" >add<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_edit" value="s1_t1_edit" >edit<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_delete" value="s1_t1_delete" >delete<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tab2<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_view" value="s1_t2_view" >view<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_add" value="s1_t2_add" >add<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_edit" value="s1_t2_edit" >edit<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_delete" value="s1_t2_delete" >delete<br>



Screen2<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tab1<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_view" value="s2_t1_view" >view<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_add" value="s2_t1_add" >add<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_edit" value="s2_t1_edit" >edit<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_delete" value="s2_t1_delete" >delete<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tab2<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_view" value="s2_t2_view" >view<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_add" value="s2_t2_add" >add<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_edit" value="s2_t2_edit" >edit<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_delete" value="s2_t2_delete" >delete<br>
<input type="submit" name="sumbit" text="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @machineaddict Please scroll left

Comment: Wow ! first of all, don't use non-breaking space to do your layout... then simply google your request : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `each`:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.is(":checked")) {
       // Item is checked
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsmwY/

Comment: Hey, just a pointer, seems like `// Item is not checked` should be `// Item is checked`, right?

Answer (score 5):

See [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NwpVt/).

If is enough, you can get all checked checkboxes using the the selector.

#### Checked:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(_, value) {
    console.log('checked: '+$(value).val());
});
```

#### Not checked:

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function(_, value) {
    console.log('not checked: '+$(value).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {

   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //Do the stuff
    }
})
```

or simple select the selected ones like

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
{
   var checkedBox = $(this);
  // Do whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 2):

sample method

```
getChecked(){
    var idString;
    //get only checked checkbox
    $('input[type=checkbox] :checked').each(function(){
    //create string of ids
    idString=idString+$(this).attr("id")+",";
    });
return idString;
    }
```