# Identify Checked checkboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I create Multiple checkBox under the one `div` with `data-role="controlgroup"` Now i want to check that after click on specific button which check boxes are checked using `JQuery` so what is the best way for do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of checked checkboxes in a div using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this you can get all of your checked `ckeckboxes`

code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery)

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
if ($("div[data-role='controlgroup'] input[type='checkbox']").first().prop("checked")) {
    // ...
}
```

That's a pretty hefty selector, and it'll only fetch the **first** `<input type="checkbox" />` that's inside a `<div data-role="controlgroup">`. You should tweak it to make it more specific to your project.

In short, jQuery's **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method with `"checked"` as the argument will return a Boolean `true` or `false` depending on whether a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

use **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

```
$("div[data-role='controlgroup'] :checkbox :checked")// by this you get all checked checkbox
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```
$("div[data-role='controlgroup'] input:checkbox :checked")
```