# How to retrieve form element value using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML code. I have made number of checkboxes. I want to retrieve the checked checkboxes's value using jquery. How can I do that?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="apple" name="box[]">apple     
<input type="checkbox" value="mango" name="box[]">Mango
<input type="checkbox" value="strawberry" name="box[]">Strawberry
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2155672/1300817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('input:checked').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry in a confusion, i just edited your answer with my answer. just now rolled back it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, OK :). PS did that confusion extend to the first line of your answer - `.map()`?

Comment: Confusion did win.. :P :( deleted my answer..