# JS output all checked input fields values before form submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have an order form with several checkbox input fields. I want to show the user the selection made before submitting the form. The js script shown bellow works as intended if the user checks a box the value of that box is showed in the paragraph. The problem is that every additional checked checkbox overrides the previous shown result.

How do I change the script to output all the checked checkbox?

This is the PHP form:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="1" name="1">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="2" name="2">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="3" name="3">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="4" name="4">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="5" name="5">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="6" name="6">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" value="7" name="7">
```

The JavaScript i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggleCheckbox(element){
        if (element.checked){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = element.value;
        }
        else document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
} 
</script>
```

The HTML field:

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**+=** not **=**

```
    function toggleCheckbox(element){
       if (element.checked)
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += " " + element.value;
       else 
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML.replace(element.value, "");
    }
```

Comment: That did the trick. Still, any idea how to change the else part to remove only the item that was unchecked?

Comment: Top class! Thanks a lot for the quick replies :D