# get multiple checked value in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have status id defined in my div tag which is present in a phtml file .Now, I need to fetch its value into the seprate javascript file.

I have use jquery push method for this.

Code in phtml file :

```
<table class="abc">
<tbody id="checkboxes">
<tr class="r<?php echo $item['id']; ?><?php echo ($item['status_low']?' status-low':''); ?>">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="item" class="row" statusid="<?php echo $item['status_id']; ?>"</td>
                    <td><?php echo $item['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item['title']; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Code in Javascript File :

```
 var selected = [];
    $('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
       if ($(this).checked) {
           selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));
       }
    });
    console.log(selected);
```

When I print selected array, I get a blank output .

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: can you post the rendered HTML, I don't see a container `#checkboxes` there.

Comment: where id checkboxes exists ?

Comment: Sorry Guys I have added it now

Comment: If you have already chosen `checked` `input`s, then what for you checked it again using `if`, also doing it in incorrect way?

Comment: @regent : i have used that code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: There is no `if` in mentioned question. Just remove `if` in your code, and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your `if` condition like bellow. Your selector is just for selected checkboxes, So you don't need that if anyway.

```
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
       selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/97/)

Comment: That's I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
var selected = [];
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));
  }
});
```

OR

```
var selected = [];
$("#checkboxes input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));
  }
});
```

OR

```
var selected = [];
$("#checkboxes input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));
});
```

Comment: Even this works out as required !
Thanks exception for exceptional help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your JQuery code like this,

```
$('#checkboxes input:checked')
```

to

```
$("#checkboxes input[type='checked']")
```

your code is:::

```
var selected = [];
    $("#checkboxes input[type='checked']").each(function() {

           selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));

    });
    console.log(selected);
```

Comment: The problem is in incorrect and unnecessary `$(this).checked`, not in inputs' selector.

Answer (score 0):

"#checkboxes input:checked" selector already selecting checked checkboxes so you don't need to check if checkbox is checked or not. See here http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
var selected = $.map('#checkboxes input:checked',function(ck,i){
   return $(ck).attr('statusid');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one

```
 var selected = $('#checkboxes input:checkbox:checked.row').map(function () {
             var cbId = this.id;
             return cbId;
         }).get();
```