# How to fetch the Id's of checkboxes selected in form of an array in a table

Tags: jquery

I have a Table as shown below

```
<table id="sample_1" aria-describedby="sample_1_info">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"></th>
         <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="odd gradeX">
      <tr>
         <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="1"></td>
         <td width="37%">Chips And Chocolates,Bummy Chips,Plain Salted,ytrytr,hyryr</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="2"></td>
         <td width="37%">Chips And Chocolates</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>


       <input type="button" class="btn blue" value="Delete" id="deletebtn">

       $('#selecctall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
if(this.checked) { // check select status
    $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
    });
}else{
    $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
    });         
}
```

});

```
$( "#deletebtn" ).click(function() {
  var $checked = $('#sample_1').find(":checkbox:checked");

      if (!$checked.length) {
        alert('Need to select atlease one checkbox button');
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

     else {

       // Here 

     }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvbucy4y/

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: If the checkbox is selected how can i fetch its id ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of checked checkboxes in a div using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
else {
     var ids = [];
     $.each($checked, function(i,e){
        console.log(e);
        if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selecctall'){
            ids.push($(e).attr("id"))
        }
 });
```

Comment: How can i remove selectall from the result ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vd56vf14/)** See the console.

```
    $('#deletebtn').click(function() {
        var array = $('#sample_1 input:checked');
        var ids = new Array();
        $.each(array, function(idx, obj) {
            ids.push($(obj).attr('id'));

        });
        console.log(ids);
    });
```

Comment: Its working fine , can i get the result in form of an array ??

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

```
var chkIds = $('#sample_1 :checkbox:checked:not(#selecctall)').map(function(i,n) {
    return $(n).attr('id');
}).get().join(',');
    alert(chkIds);
```

**Answer Updated:** you have to use`:not()` to exclude the first CheckBox.

Comment: How can i remove selectall from the result ? –

Comment: @PreethiJain - See the updated answer. It will exclude the `selecctall` Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not bothering to get the `id` of the checked elements, and simply use the nodes:

```
$("#deletebtn").click(function () {
    // retrieve a jQuery collection of the checked <input>s from the <tbody>
    // which means we ignore the 'select-all' checkbox):
    var $checked = $('#sample_1 tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    // if we have any checked elements:
    if ($checked.length) {
        // we find the closest <tr> elements to those checked <inputs>, and
        // remove them:
        $checked.closest('tr').remove();
    } else {
        // otherwise, we alert:
        alert("You need to check at least one checkbox.");
    }

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tvbucy4y/2/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).