# Get selected checkboxes from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkboxes inside a dropdown menu. I've to get the checkboxes which are selected (checked)

**Code:**

```
  <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="comp">
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Monday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Tuesday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Wednesday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Thursday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Friday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
    /* Get selected check boxes here */
    }
</script>
```

Comment: using `javascript` or `jquery`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of checked checkboxes in a div using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: I've tried. It's not working

Comment: show how you've tried.. On what event you want to get the selected checkboxes?

Comment: @krish, On which event you are accessing the states of the `check-boxes` ? How does your JS look like ?

Comment: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"> , onclick event...

Comment: @krish, `checkbox` should have a `value` attribute.. How will you differentiate ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/byues358/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution also. Here you will get the checked checkbox elements list. You can also update this checked element list during run time also.

Check the following demo:

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c453wf45/1/)

**Stack Example**

```js
$(function() {
  var checkedItems = $("#comp input:checked");
  console.log(checkedItems);
  $("#comp input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
      checkedItems.push($(this)[0]);//Add the checked element
      console.log(checkedItems);
    } else {
      checkedItems.splice($.inArray($(this)[0], checkedItems), 1);//Remove the unchecked element
      console.log(checkedItems);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="comp">

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox" id="a1">
      <span class="lbl"> Monday</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox" id="a2">
      <span class="lbl"> Tuesday</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox" id="a3" checked="checked">
      <span class="lbl"> Wednesday</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox" id="a4">
      <span class="lbl"> Thursday</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox" id="a5">
      <span class="lbl"> Friday</span>
    </a>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `console` for selected `checkboxes`.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var checkBoxes=$("#comp input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    console.log(checkBoxes);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="comp">
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Monday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Tuesday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Wednesday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Thursday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"> Friday</span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it, it will return all selected checkbox values as you select any checkbox:

```
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="comp">
    <li><a href="#">
    <input name="chklist" onclick="get_selected_val()" value="monday" type="checkbox">
    <span class="lbl"> Monday</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
    <input name="chklist" onclick="get_selected_val()" value="tuesday" type="checkbox">
    <span class="lbl"> Tuesday</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
    <input name="chklist" value="wednesday" onclick="get_selected_val()" type="checkbox">
    <span class="lbl"> Wednesday</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
    <input name="chklist" onclick="get_selected_val()" value="thursday" type="checkbox">
    <span class="lbl"> Thursday</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
    <input name="chklist" onclick="get_selected_val()"  value="friday" type="checkbox">
    <span class="lbl"> Friday</span>
    </a></li>
</ul>


function get_selected_val() {
 $('input[name="chklist"]:checked').each(function() {
   console.log(this.value);
 });
}
```