# How to get the Value of a checkbox from JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some checkboxes and want to add their value into JQuery.  I have been able to retrieve the value but it gets every checkbox value with the .each jquery command.  I wasn't sure how to get only the value of that specific checkbox that is checked so I can use the append command to display the data.

The checkbox:

```
<input id="add_policies_checkbox<?php echo $row[toolID]; ?>" type="checkbox" value=<?php echo $row[toolID]; ?> />
```

The button that submits the form for JQuery to handle:

```
<input type="button" name="action" class="btn btn-success checkboxadd" value="Add Policy" />
```

JQuery - Not sure how to get only the information (value) from the  add_policies_checkbox that is checked:

```
$(".checkboxadd").click(function(){
                    $('[id*="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(){
                      //alert(this.value);
                      var data=this.value;
                      $("#div_to_add_this_checkbox_value").append("Info added"+data);
                    });
});//end ajaxifypolicies
```

Comment: However, your checkboxes don't have any value

Comment: Use `:checked` selector?

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of checked checkboxes in a div using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Multiple checkbox can be checked. Which value you need?

Comment: My problem is that every add_policies_checkbox input id is diferent.  add_policies_checkbox1, add_policies_checkbox2, etc....  So that is why I need a database driven approach towards it otherwise a simple ID tag would work.  The Value has the ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]` as selector to loop over all checkboxes with id starting with `add_policies_checkbox` and check their `checked` property

```js
$(".checkboxadd").click(function(){
                    $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                      //alert(this.value);
                      if($(v).prop('checked')){
                      var data=$(v).val();
                      $("#div_to_add_this_checkbox_value").append("Info added"+data);}
                    });
});//end ajaxifypolicies
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="something1" id="add_policies_checkbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="something2" id="add_policies_checkbox2"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="something3" id="add_policies_checkbox3"/>
<button class="checkboxadd">Submit</button>
<div id="div_to_add_this_checkbox_value"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Sol Happy to help! :) I can see how much you had to explain your question. Took a while for me to figure out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use  **$.fn.prop** :

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked');
// return true or false
```

Comment: $('[id*="add_policies_checkbox"]:checkbox').prop('checked');    Is this how I should do this?

Comment: Each add_policies_checkbox has a number, add_policies_checkbox1, add_policies_checkbox2, etc....  Thinking about it I could make class for this if that is possible, I just need every checkbox to be it's own unique ID.

Comment: will return for only one checkbox....not sure what this is supposed to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, see the changes below:

```
$(".checkboxadd").click(function(){
                $('#add_policies_checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                  //alert(this.value);
                  var data = $(this).value
                  $("#div_to_add_this_checkbox_value").append("Info added"+data);
                });
});//end ajaxifypolicies
```