# Checked in table html

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
 $('.sus').click(function(e) {
    
    if($(".case").is(":checked")){
     for (var i = Things.length; i >= 0; i++) {
      Things[i]
     }
     alert("checkeado");
    }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success sus">Success</button>
<div class="container">
 
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Checkbox</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>
      <input type="Checkbox" class="case">
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>
      <input type="Checkbox" class="case">
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
        <td>
      <input type="Checkbox" class="case">
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to make ckecked to be showing me the first name of which is ckecked.

As shown in the picture

Or make a for which to cross the table and show me the ones that are checked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf32D.png)

Comment: You are counting up....so you have an infinite loop.  What is `Things`?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: how can you do what? Not have an infinite loop? Count down, not up.

Comment: Ignore the for was trying to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155622/get-a-list-of-checked-checkboxes-in-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: Need to provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what it is you are trying to do and how you want it displayed. Use a translation service if you have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. You will need to remove the extra comma (,) at the end.

```js
$(function() {
 $('.sus').click(function(e) {
    var checkedNames = '';
    var $things = $('.case:checked');
    if($things.length > 0){
     for (var i = 0; i < $things.length; i++) {
         checkedNames += $($things[i]).closest('tr').find('td:first').text() + ',';
     }
     alert("checkeado " + checkedNames);
    }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success sus">Success</button>
<div class="container">
 
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Checkbox</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>
      <input type="Checkbox" class="case">
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>
      <input type="Checkbox" class="case">
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
        <td>
      <input type="Checkbox" class="case">
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
```